# CTCoreMessage setTo parameter?

Tags: objective-c, ios, mailcore

Can someone help me with calling the `setTo` function of `CTCoreMessage`?
I'm sending `NSSet` as a parameter but it's giving a runtime error. My code is:

```
CTCoreAddress *to=[CTCoreAddress alloc];
[to setEmail:@"someone@someone.com"];
NSSet *set=[[NSSet alloc]initWithObjects:to,nil];
CTCoreMessage *message=[CTCoreMessage alloc];
[message setTo:set];
```

everything works perfect when I write the line

```
 [message setTo:set];
```

following runtime error is generated:

```
err =  mailimf_address_list_add_mb(imfList, strdup(addressName), strdup(addressEmail));
```

> Thread1:program received signal "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Comment: You don't `init` the `to` object.

Comment: helped me to though in slightly different task but the problem was the same not alloc/init NSSet variable